# How can I enable a face browser in LightDM?

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

Is there a way to enable face display in the default LightDM greeter in Oneiric? If not, is there another alternative greeter that supports faces?

(I know I can switch back to gdm if necessary, but I assume *somebody* must have this working with LightDM...)

Answer (score 7):

[lightdm-webkit-greeter](https://launchpad.net/lightdm-webkit-greeter) is under development with [some packaging](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily/+build/2818399) already being done for Ubuntu 11.10.

`lightdm-webkit-greeter` is a webkit themer for `lightdm` that allows distros and users to create themes.

There is a [lightdm face browser theme](https://code.launchpad.net/~and471/lightdm-webkit-greeter/facebrowser-theme) proposal but everything is a bit far from final.

Best thing you can do at the moment if you are interested in having a face browser lightdm theme is really subscribe to the project and keep checking the progress being done.